# Chasing one's tail about what HTML is supported

Tags: feature-request, jobs, design

I was experimenting with the "personal statement" field of my Careers profile and found that I could seemingly get fairly fancy with embedded HTML because it displayed nicely in the preview. Upon saving it though it was all stripped leaving just a run-on paragraph. "Wow!" I thought to myself, "that appears to be quite a major gaff with SO... so what am I missing?" Well, immediately below the field it states *"This text field supports [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) formatting."* Following the link to the Markdown web pages, I went to the [Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) page and the [Inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) section. It states "For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself." and goes on to state that the *only* restrictions involve whitespace considerations. **Thus, following the available information, my HTML tables and divs should have worked.**

Before posting a "Hey, I found a huge bug, folks!" I delved further and found [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) that talks about, as you likely know, which HTML tags are permitted on SO sites. It even directly addresses my conundrum: *"HTML tags not on this list are stripped from the output. They may render in the client preview but they will always be removed on the server."*

My point here is that the system as it stands now leads users to a roadblock and/or a source of frustration. It goes against the driving principle of SO -- *to make things delightfully easy for the user.*

My call to action, then, is simply to change the text below the field from this:

```
This text field supports Markdown formatting.
```

...to this:

```
This text field supports Markdown formatting *with limitations*.
```

... with *limitations* linked to the MSO FAQ link given above.

Comment: It would be nice if the preview was actually a preview, too.